# Trying to send email to dynamic receiver with laravel

Tags: laravel

I was sending email to a static email and it was working but when I tried to send to a dynamic user getting data from the DB it returned  this error: `Expected response code 250 but got code "530"`, with message `"530 5.7.1 Authentication required"`

my sending email function:

```php
public function send_email()
{   
    $getStaff=DB::table('users')
        ->OrderBy('id','DESC')
        ->first();

    $staffacckey=$getStaff->access_key;
    $staffemail=$getStaff->email;

    $valueurl = env('APP_URL');

    $info = array();
    $info['url']=$valueurl;
    $info['name']='tinox';
    $info['msg']='test';
    $info['key']=$staffacckey;

    Mail::send('email.mail',$info, function($email) {
        $ghost='no-reply@domain.com';
        $admin='System Administrator';
        $email->from($ghost, $admin);
        $email->to($staffemail)->subject('email confirmation');
    });       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function send_email()
    {   
        $getStaff=DB::table('staff')
        ->OrderBy('staff_id','DESC')
        ->first();
        $staffacckey=$getStaff->access_key;
        global $staffemail;
        $staffemail=$getStaff->email;
        $valueOne = env('APP_URL');
        $info = array();
        $info['url']=$valueOne.':8080';
        $info['name']='tinox';
        $info['msg']='test';
        $info['key']=$staffacckey;
        $info['email']=$staffemail;
        Mail::send('email.mail',$info,
        function($email)use ($info){
            $ghost='no-reply@magazinelte.com';
            $admin='System Administrator';
            $email->from($ghost, $admin);
            $email->to($info['email'])->subject('Account activation');
        });

    }

just fixed the issue!! Passed variables inside the Mail function and change my env
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*******@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```